# Android Studio logger TextView TypeFace style 0

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, logcat, typeface

In my project, I receive the following in a `logcat` message, for each `TextView` in all views of my app:

```
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
```

The theme I used in `styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="GreenTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryGreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkGreen</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentGreen</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I also use `buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"`

I have also tried to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as the parent theme. The messages still get logged.

**UPDATE 1**

After some tests i have found that this occurs only with `*.Theme.AppCompat.Light.*` themes.

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` is most often used and comes in every tutorial for material design.

How can this issue be fixed?

**UPDATE 2**

*Note*: When using an emulator, this message does not show. It's most likely a device issue.

Comment: try to add this line   <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
in your style.

Comment: has not helped.

Comment: This started to show up for me aswell. Reason of it  was upgrading buildtoolsversion to 26

Comment: Did you find the cause of the log?

Comment: @ThomasVos, as in previous message and my last update was say: this occurs by `buildtoolsversion` 26 and only on real device. More have i not found.

Comment: I have this also. Using build tools 27.0.0 and using support library 27.0.1. Using a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 in my project.

Comment: Anyone have a clue for this log issue ? i'm running on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2016

Comment: anyone got any update on this issue ? it's extremely annoying

Comment: This stuff goes to release version as well and slows down UI. Scrolling becomes laggy on Samsung Galaxy tab smt models. I can't get rid of them using ProGuard

Answer (score 30):

On logcat, right click and select "Fold lines like this" then edit down that line to just the bit from "TextView..." - then they all disappear.

Comment: Thanks! After many years in Android studio I found this feature just now :)

Answer (score 11):

this might be a Samsung specific issue. you probably could try to replace all instances of `TextView` with `AppCompatTextView` and see if those warnings get any less... while this is just a wild guess.

would suggest to mute the noise; goto `Logcat` > `Edit Filter Configuration` and then include the packagename (in order to resemble the option "Show only selected application") - and exclude that annoying tag with an exclusive regular expression, alike: `^(?!TextView)` or exclude by log message `^(?!setTypeface\swith\sstyle\s:\s0)`.this should reduce the amount of log spam.