# Getting log as TextView: setTypeface with style : 0 on samsung device only

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts, android-typeface

When I run my application on samsung Galaxy Tab, I am getting "TextView: setTypeface with style : 0" line printed in my log file and my app gets stuck at the same time or its crashing some of the time.

Anyone knows what is the exact meaning of this.

Any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Add your code .

Comment: Which code you want?  the layout file of java code. This is not an error from the code, its printing on log when I run my application only on Samsung devices

Comment: `when I run my application only on Samsung devices` ? i.e only your code is responsible for it isn't it ?  [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464361/android-studio-logger-textview-typeface-style-0).